# JSF- h:panelGrid specific style for specific column

Tags: css, jsf

There is `h:panelGrid` table with 2 columns.

It's needed,that first column to be `30%` and the second one `70%` of whole table width.

Is there some configuration for such case?
Looks like `columnClasses` attribute applied for all columns,
 and it's needed specific CSS class for specific column.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use column-separated list of classes: `columnClasses="column1Class, column2Class"`. By documentation the `column1Class` will be used for the first column and the `column2Class` for the second column.

Comment: The value of the columnClasses attribute is split strictly by commas, whitespace is preserved. So, multiple CSS classes may be specified for each column.